# website Url redirect from organic search to home page

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, seo

All my website product urls redirect from organic search to my home page.

Here is my issue :

For eg ., I have a url named xyz.com/product/product-id.html

when I searched this url on google.com it redirects to my home page xyz.com

Can I know how to fix this issue, Most of my urls redirect like this to home page.

thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Post your current .htaccess rules?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System->Configuration->Web->Url Options` and set the field `Auto-redirect to Base URL` to `No`.
Then clear the cache just in case.